# 2 Separate Tasks - Related but first needs to finish completely

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

Right now I have an app that will be inserting thousands of rows with a click of a button. They populate a table within the database (or many tables but lets keep it simple) and anything that is inserted or updated needs to be calculated/recalculated using a stored procedure. Initially I had a trigger there that looked for anything modified and passed the parameters to the stored procedure but it's taking too long. Then I had the thought to just insert the parameter values into a "queue" table and have the stored proc read from there. I placed a trigger on this queue table initially thinking once an insert happens, we can run the proc and then have the record removed from the queue table... but a trigger that inserts into another table with a trigger is still linked and is taking a while for the process to finish. I want to keep these tasks related but separate. I want the first trigger to run through, dump all the values into the queue table and completely finish before the SP is kicked off. Is my best bet to have the values in this queue table and set up a job that runs every 10 seconds to see if anything is in there or is there another approach you can recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what I'm going to do after some thinking is have the trigger on the queue table still but instead of it triggering the stored proc, it will kick off a job. That way it can go quickly through instead of waiting for the process. The job itself will have a stored proc that looks back at the queue table and performs the necessary steps before removing the record.